# Keras with Lambda layers for custom activation

Tags: keras, lambda

In an attempt to apply 3 different activation functions to the 3 columns of the last Dense layer I'm using Lambda layers. First I split and then reassemble the output. No actual activation is applied as of yet, because I found that the following gives me an error at the model fit step:

```
def createModel():
in_put = Input(shape=(3300,))
layer1 = Dense(512, activation='relu')(in_put)
layer2 = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(layer1)
layer3 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(layer2)
out_put = Dense(3)(layer3)

#splitting output into 3 columns for further activation
theta = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,0], output_shape=(1,))(out_put)
phi = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,1], output_shape=(1,))(out_put)
r = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,2], output_shape=(1,))(out_put)

#combining the activated layers (activation has not been implemented yet) 
out_put_a = Lambda(lambda x: K.stack([x[0], x[1], x[2]]),output_shape=(3,),  name="output")([theta, phi, r])

model = Model(inputs=in_put, outputs=out_put_a)
return model

my_network=createModel()

batch_size = 1000
epochs = 1

my_network.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mean_squared_error')
history = my_network.fit_generator(generator=training_generator, epochs=epochs, 
                validation_data=testing_generator)
```

It crashes with the following error:

> InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
>     (0) Invalid argument: Incompatible shapes: [3] vs. [1000]
>        [[{{node training/RMSprop/gradients/loss/output_loss/mul_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs}}]]
>        [[loss/mul/_55]]
>     (1) Invalid argument: Incompatible shapes: [3] vs. [1000]
>        [[{{node training/RMSprop/gradients/loss/output_loss/mul_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs}}]]
>   0 successful operations.
>   0 derived errors ignored.>

At the same time the code below (with no Lambda layers works just fine):

```
def createModel():
in_put = Input(shape=(3300,))
layer1 = Dense(512, activation='relu')(in_put)
layer2 = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(layer1)
layer3 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(layer2)
out_put = Dense(3)(layer3)

model = Model(inputs=in_put, outputs=out_put)
return model

my_network=createModel()

batch_size = 1000
epochs = 1

my_network.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mean_squared_error')
history = my_network.fit_generator(generator=training_generator, epochs=epochs, 
                validation_data=testing_generator)
```

Could anyone point out what's wrong with the lambda layer?

Comment: the batch_size is actually determined by the generator based on from "keras.utils import Sequence", but it does equal 1000

Comment: You probably wanted `K.stack([x[0], x[1], x[2]], axis=1)` (or `axis=-1`, as the default is 0). Alternatively, just `keras.layers.concatenate([x[0], x[1], x[2]])` layer instead of that lambda.

Comment: Hi @Kit, yes, axis=1 solves it. Many thanks!!!